# How to conduct SAS Proc SurveyFreq with strata in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to run a survey analysis in Python that I know how to do in SAS:

```
proc surveyfreq data=df;
    table  C01Q01 /  cl;
    strata strata;
    weight wtfinal;
run;
```

I'm currently searching for answers/packages and have found some for weighted analysis but so far I'm not sure how to incorporate strata into the analysis.

Here is an example of the kind of output I want to create (this was made using the code above more or less):

[Sample Proc SurveyFreq Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNXQI.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide more information about specifically what you are trying to achieve, and the expected output?

Comment: Using the code block above I created [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNXQI.png) table as an example. This is the sort of table I want to create in Python but I'm not sure how to do it. Especially using strata.