# Is there an R-svydesign equivalent in Python to apply complex survey design weights?

Tags: python, weighted

Is there a way to incorporate survey weights from complex survey designs to conduct descriptive statistics (e.g., frequencies and crosstabs) and linear/logistical regressions and modeling?

Analyzing survey datasets with complex survey designs typically involve stratification and clustering to represent larger populations ([e.g., CDC National Health Interview Survey. p 41](https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Dataset_Documentation/NHIS/2021/srvydesc-508.pdf)).

Couple of posts [Design-corrected Variance Estimation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73212764) and [How to conduct SAS Proc SurveyFreq with strata in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378247/how-to-conduct-sas-proc-surveyfreq-with-strata-in-python)mention the [samplics](https://github.com/samplics-org/samplics), [Quantipy](https://github.com/Quantipy/quantipy/tree/staging-develop) and [PandaSurvey](https://github.com/InContextSolutions/PandaSurvey)  packages.

Unfortunately, none of those packages really enable survey data analysis and documentation is quite limited.

In R, I know this is doable with survey package, applying the surveydesign to the dataframe by:

```
# Readin data
df = read_dta('data.dta')

# Define survey design
design <- svydesign(id=~ID, weights=~analwt ,strata=~Final_strata, data=df)

# Apply survey weights
df_weighted <- svydesign(id=~ID, weights=~analwt, strata=~Final_strata, nest=TRUE, survey.lonely.psu="adjust",data=df)

# Crosstab
xtab = svytable(~var1+var2, df_weighted) %>%
  prop.table(1)*100
```

And in SAS an example can be:

```
proc surveyfreq data=PS_Data;
tables INT4a; strata
final_strata; cluster granteeid;
weight analwt;
run;
```

In STATA, this is done by:

```
Svyset GranteeID [pweight=ANALWT], strata(Final_strata) vce(linearized)
Then use the svy prefix for analysis commands.
```

I've tried the crosstab function in pandas but it doesn't seem to have the ability to account for the strat/clustering.

```
xtab_weighted = pd.crosstab(
    df['var1'], df['var2'], 
    df.analwt,
    aggfunc=sum, dropna=True, normalize=True)
```

Comment: yes,  it is more than likely that this is possible in python.  if you can show what you are trying to achieve (with a simple input and output example), then this would be mist useful....  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, though I'm not sure how pandas is or is not accounting for the stratified survey sampling.

I had to change the normalize='columns' in pd.crosstab() to normalize='index'.

```
> # Load libraries 
> library(pacman)
> p_load(haven, survey, gmodels)
> 
> # Read data
> df = read_dta('hcps_puf_2022.dta')
> 
> head(df[c('GranteeID', 'analwt', 'Final_strata', 'race_simp', 'INT4')])
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  GranteeID analwt Final_strata race_simp              INT4     
      <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl+lbl>              <dbl+lbl>
1  10001141   624.            7 1 [Hispanic]           2 [No]   
2  10001254 12550.            7 4 [Other]              1 [Yes]  
3  10001148 11080.            6 1 [Hispanic]           1 [Yes]  
4  10001056  6382.            7 3 [Non-Hispanic Black] 2 [No]   
5  10001056  1666.            7 1 [Hispanic]           2 [No]   
6  10000019  1113.            5 3 [Non-Hispanic Black] 2 [No]   
> 
> # Apply survey design
> design <- svydesign(id=~GranteeID, weights=~analwt, strata=~Final_strata, data=df)
> 
> # Create the weighted dataset
> df_weighted <- svydesign(id=~GranteeID, weights=~analwt,strata=~Final_strata,nest=TRUE,survey.lonely.psu="adjust",data=df)
> 
> class(df_weighted)
[1] "survey.design2" "survey.design" 
> class(df)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> 
> # Print an unweighted crosstab
> table = table(df$race_simp, df$INT4)
> print(table)
   
      -1    1    2
  1    4 1404  461
  2    0   57  998
  3    0   61  825
  4    0  277  327
> 
> prop = prop.table(table)
> print(prop*100)
   
             -1           1           2
  1  0.09062075 31.80788401 10.44404169
  2  0.00000000  1.29134572 22.60987766
  3  0.00000000  1.38196647 18.69053013
  4  0.00000000  6.27548709  7.40824649
> 
> # Print a weighted crosstab
> xtab = svytable(~race_simp+INT4, df_weighted) %>%
+   prop.table(1)*100
> print(xtab)
         INT4
race_simp         -1          1          2
        1  0.3178533 75.6193499 24.0627968
        2  0.0000000  4.2014280 95.7985720
        3  0.0000000  9.3431736 90.6568264
        4  0.0000000 49.7183264 50.2816736
```

Here's the python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyreadstat

# Load the data
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_dta ('hcps_puf_2022.dta')

print(df[['GranteeID', 'analwt', 'Final_strata', 'race_simp','INT4']].head())

# Print unweighted crosstab
table = pd.crosstab(df['race_simp'], df['INT4'])
print(table)

prop = pd.crosstab(df['race_simp'], df['INT4'],
                   normalize='all')
print(prop*100)

# Print weighted crosstab
xtab = pd.crosstab(df['race_simp'], df['INT4'], df['analwt'], 
                   dropna=True, aggfunc=sum, normalize='index')
print(xtab*100)
   GranteeID        analwt  Final_strata  race_simp  INT4
0   10001141    623.704488             7          1     2
1   10001254  12550.269662             7          4     1
2   10001148  11079.553945             6          1     1
3   10001056   6382.018253             7          3     2
4   10001056   1665.617379             7          1     2
INT4       -1     1    2
race_simp               
1           4  1404  461
2           0    57  998
3           0    61  825
4           0   277  327
INT4             -1          1          2
race_simp                                
1          0.090621  31.807884  10.444042
2          0.000000   1.291346  22.609878
3          0.000000   1.381966  18.690530
4          0.000000   6.275487   7.408246
INT4             -1          1          2
race_simp                                
1          0.317853  75.619350  24.062797
2          0.000000   4.201428  95.798572
3          0.000000   9.343174  90.656826
4          0.000000  49.718326  50.281674
```